# Link is not clicked in mobile

Tags: javascript, html, css, jquery-mobile, samsung-mobile

I have built a Suggest button for my players, which you can view live [here](http://cgi.di.uoa.gr/~grad1459/cage_scheduler.php#input_page). It works in the iPhone of my best friend and since I do not haven a modern cellphone, it works o my broswer's device mode, which however does not list that specific device that seems to have the problem. Users using android report that it works there too!

I am using jQuery mobile and the problem is produced in Samsung galaxy s3 neo, when using Chrome browser.

The HTML is:

```
<a id="search_btn" data-role="button" class="ui-btn ui-corner-all ui-shadow ui-btn-inline ui-icon-search ui-btn-icon-left">Show me the players</a>
```

and the JS:

```
$(window).load(function() {
    ...
    $("#search_btn").click(function(){
        alert("marievi leeeme!"); // that user can not even see this!
        var slot = 0;
        ...
```

Any ideas? I do not have a clue. Maybe it's because I am using an `a` tag instead of a real button?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
     var self = this;
     $("#search_btn").click(function(){
        self.alert("marievi leeeme!"); // that user can not even see this!
        var slot = 0;
     });
});
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but this will produce an error when I am using it: `Uncaught TypeError: self.alert is not a function`

Comment: what about window.alert("marievi leeeme!");   ?

Comment: I will ask that user and report back.